# ArrayHeap Class not returning sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, heap

I'm using java.

Here is the code for my class:

```
/**
 * Ensure that the ordering property of the heap holds after
 * the insertion of an new element into the heap.
 */
private void interchangeUp() {
    int current = size - 1;
    int parent = (current - 1) / 2;

    while(parent <= 0 && heapForm[current].compareTo(heapForm[parent]) < 0) {
        swap(parent, current);
        current = parent;
        parent = (current - 1) / 2;
    }
}
```

I've looked over my code and can't seem to figure out what is causing this issue.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Instead of dumping 100 lines of code on us, use a debugger to more closely identify where the issue is.

Comment: I mentioned which methods where I think the problems may be. I only listed the whole class just in case. No need to be rude. Maybe try reading?

Comment: You think you've done enough before asking this question. I'm telling you you haven't. Always debug your code before posting such a question. If you've done that, present your results (which should be more than "I think the problem is here").

Comment: What kind of results am I going to get from debugging when there are no errors in my code? It's just not doing what I want.

Comment: Here's the debug: Listening on javadebug
User program running
User program finished debug:
Here is the array to be sorted:
30 10 74 48 97 
Here is the sorted array:
10 30 48 74 97

Comment: Debugging as in stepping through your code one statement at a time and investigating its state. You might not have compilation errors but if the code isn't behaving as you expect or want, it has a bug.

Comment: And yes that array is sorted but only by chance. It does not return sorted everytime.

Comment: And you think I haven't done that?

Comment: You're doing nothing but starting a flame war. So congratulations.

Comment: What flame war? I'm asking you to improve your question with your debugging results. This will help identify your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small bug in algorithm:

```
private void interchangeUp() {
    int current = size - 1;
    int parent = (current - 1) / 2;

    //while (parent <= 0 && heapForm[current].compareTo(heapForm[parent]) < 0) {
    while (parent >= 0 && heapForm[current].compareTo(heapForm[parent]) < 0) {
        swap(parent, current);
        current = parent;
        parent = (current - 1) / 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much. I had been looking over this code for a few days. I just needed a new set of eyes. I appreciate the help.